# position: absolute, div under div

Tags: css

I've 3 divs, each of them has `position: absolute`.

First is header, and its working.

Header has constant height, and second div "content" also works.

Third div is "footer".

"Content" has changeable height and when "content" is higher than web-browser window the "footer" is ON "content". I want to "footer" under "content" irrespective of content height.

My header is 300px height, content has `margin-top: 300px`. I can't use the same for the footer, because content hasn't got constant height.

I don't want to set one div with `position: absolute`, and these 3 divs place inside this one.

```
div#header{
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
  position: absolute;
 }

div#content{
 width: 960px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -480px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 200px;
 }

div#footer{
  width: 960px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; /*with this i've div fixed to the bottom of web-browsers' window */
  clear: both;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add example code to the question?

Comment: You can also create "fiddles" here: http://jsfiddle.net/ for examples.

Answer (score 3):

You're over positioning.

You do not need to position everything absolutely unless there's something you aren't sharing.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/uhopil/3/edit)

Answer (score 1):

***If you are willing to use*** `position : relative` which is a tad better than `position : absolute` in cases like this, http://jsfiddle.net/vFTXg/1/ - Try editing the value of your content's height here and your footer will be automatically adjusted.

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position : relative;
    width : 100%;
    height : 90px;
    background-color : #000;
}
.content{
    position:relative;
    width : 100%;
    min-height : 200px;
    background-color : #f00;
}
.footer{
    position:relative;
    width : 100%;
    height : 50px;
    background-color : #0f0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='content'></div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CSS floats

Do something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Set the site-width on the wrapper and let the other divs have the same width.

Use **float:left** on header, content and footer

Set **clear:both** on the clear-div.

Now you can set the height on the elements you want to have a fixed hight - and you don't have to bother with absolute positioning.. If you insist on using positioning, you could just position the wrapper.

Comment: that is what I didn't want to use but if u recommend that. thx

Comment: If you use `overflow: hidden` on the `#wrapper`, you don't really need the clear div.

Answer (score 0):

In the future browser can calculate. For your example this could be nice to calculate the min-height for the content to set the foorter to the bottom if content height is low and to set the footer after the content if it has a heigh value. E.g.:

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="content">header</div>
<div id="content" class="content">content</div>
<div id="footer" class="content">footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
#header {
    height: 200px;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 302px);
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 302px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 302px);
}
#footer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Unfortunately only firefox and IE9 and higher support `calc` at the moment, so this is more theoretically. If you want to test it, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHLw/).
If you want to do this with all current browser you need to use javascript.

Comment: I didn't know about that. What about performance? These are calculated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be of constant width and centered try this

```
#footer,
#header,
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and forget about

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
position: absolute;
```